# When iPhone6 back to foreground, the view is getting small

Tags: iphone, screen

I get a project from my friends and it is about cam. And In iPhone 6 when I open a view, touch Home button,back to the app, the app is no more full screen.I don't know why? the iPhone5  is work well.
Please help me! many thanks.

Comment: Provide screenshots before and after the home button was pressed?

Answer (score 0):

this is not a issue, you did not set compatibility with screens. because i-phone 6 has larger screen size(375*667) than i-phone 5 screen size(320*567). therefore you have to apply checks of compatibility.

```
CGRect screenSize;
screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
NSLog(@"%f",screenSize.size.height);

float height = screenSize.size.height;
if (height == 667)//this is i-phone 6 height
{
 //change your view frame here, set according to i-phone 6 screen bounds
}
```